# how to post back php form to another page after payment success through razorpay using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Form post back to action="post_order.php" and then it redirects to orderlist.php with id

```
var options = {
"key":"rzp_test_0uREUyTRES2si4",
"amount": finalamnt,
"name": "demo_name",
"description": "Purchase Description",
"image": "images/logo.png",
"handler": function (response){
    alert("Payment Successfully Done..Order will be placed soon");
    document.getElementById('form_ordernow').submit();
    location.href = "http://www.demo.com/homepage/orderlist.php?id=";
    //document.getElementById("form_ordernow").action = "post_order.php";
    //document.getElementById("form_ordernow").submit();
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are writing javascript in the function, use Ajax to create a post request.

Another option would be to set some config in the API of razorpay which then posts back after a successful payment.